# show that joint pdf divided by pdf is pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I watched a series of lectures on probability where it is said that if we have a joint PDF f(x, y) and PDF g(y), then it is true that:

$e(x|y) = \frac{f(x, y)}{g(y)}$

where e(x|y) - is also PDF. It is mentioned that this can be somehow shown using infinitely smalls, but i couldn't quite come up with the idea cause im bad at proofs. The question - is it possible to show it somehow in an easy way? For example, in case of simple events, this can be visualized with Venn diagrams. But pdfs do not represent probability per se, they are functions, and only their integrals are probabilities.

Comment: The RHS is a function of $(x,y)$. How come the LHS should be a function of $x$ only?

Comment: oops my bad - forgot that it is dependent on y

Comment: And now, what you wrote on the RHS is rather $e(y\mid x)$, not the other way round.

Comment: yes sry i changed all =) the question still stands though i guess =)

Comment: OK, after your edit, indeed each $e(\ \mid y)$ is a PDF since $g(y)=\int f(x,y)dx$ hence $e(\ \mid y)$ is nonnegative and integrates to $1$, as desired.

Comment: But how did you come up with the idea that e(|y) integrates to 1? It is non-negative because f(x, y) and g(y) are non-negative so their quotient cannot be negative.

Comment: Because it is an arch-classical construction (namely, of conditional PDF).

Comment: Ok, then i suppose i could pose the question a little bit differently - how does one know that the result of division is a conditional pdf? maybe it is just some functions, not pdf, not conditional, just some strange function?

Comment: @Did, thank you for comments, now i got it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments to your question, a function qualifies as a PDF if it is non-negative and integrates to 1. Now since both $f(x,y)$ and $g(y)$ are non-negative so $e(x|y)$ is also non-negative. To show that it integrates to 1, first note that $g(y) = \int f(x,y)dx$. Furthermore,

$\int e(x|y)dx = \frac{1}{g(y)}\int f(x,y)dx = 1$.

Comment: Thank you I think now by looking at the equation written i understood the idea and arguments in the comments